# how to insert a text in text area with content type text/html based on cursor position?

Tags: java, swing, textarea

how to insert a text in text area with content type text/html based on cursor position?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
this is a test 
</body>
</html>
```

I need to insert a word based on cursor position(after "this") of the text area. When i use textArea.getText() method, my string is in the form of above html whereas the caret position that i get is 5. I tried retrieving the plain text but it compromises the style in the HTML. Is it possible without using external APIs? Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Use the method `replaceSelection` Luke.

Comment: You can't use a JTextArea to display HTML. You can use either a JEditorPane or JTextArea.

Comment: @camickr *"..use either a JEditorPane or JTextArea"* ITYM *"..use either a JEditorPane or JTextPane"* ..

Comment: Oops. sometimes the fingers don't type what the brain is thinking. That of course should be `JEditorPane or JTextPane`.

Comment: replace selection works!! tnks!!